# System of differential equations in economics and areas of interest

Tags: mathematical-economics, nonexpert, difference-equations

More than a question, I'm looking for suggestions of models of system of differential equations applied in economics or maybe in another area of interes.

I have a research homework and I have to make an analysis of the model and present it in front of a class and now I'm in the process of choosing the model what I'm going to talk about so any suggestion will help me a lot :)

Comment: Are you interested in models with one differential equation, or (as "system" suggests) are you looking for models with more than one differential equation?

Comment: @AdamBailey models with more than one differential equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most fundamental distinctions in economics is that between stocks, measured at a point in time, and flows, measured over a period of time or as instantaneous rates. The construction of dynamic economic models naturally leads to differential equations in which the rate of change of a stock variable depends on one or more flow variables.

An example of an economic model centred on a system of two such differential equations is the Dasgupta-Heal-Solow-Stiglitz model.  The stock variables in this model are man-made capital $K$ and non-renewable resource $S$ (the simplifying assumption is made that there is just one type of each).

In outline, the model takes output $Y$ to be a function of capital $K$ and use of the resource $R$ (a further simplifying assumption is to ignore labour input), and the rate of change of the stock of capital to equal output less consumption $C$:

$$\dot{K}=Y-C=f(K,R)-C$$

The rate of change of the stock of non-renewable resource is simply the rate of use of the resource:

$$\dot{S}=-R$$

The objective is to maximise the discounted present value of the utility $U$ derived from consumption:

$$\max_C \int_{t=0}^T e^{-\rho t}U(C(t))dt$$

For particular output and utility functions, solutions may be obtainable using the method of dynamic optimization (see for example [Benchekroun & Withagen 2010](https://www.cireqmontreal.com/wp-content/uploads/cahiers/04-2010-cah.pdf)).